# Meteor Namespacing: util methods in other files

Tags: meteor, namespaces, meteor-helper

I am new to meteor. I am having problems using my util methods in other files. I read the section on namespacing in the meteor manual and I believe it says if I make the a variable global by leaving off the 'var', I should have it in scope in all my my application files.

From the meteor documentation:

```
// Package Scope. This variable is visible to every file inside
// of this package or app. The difference is that 'var' is
// omitted.
bobPerson = {name: "bob"};
```

For the record, I am not creating a package. The following two example files are within my application itself. The files are something similar to:

my_app/lib/util.js

```
util = {
  printHelloWorld: function(){
    console.log('hello world');
  }
};
```

my_app/test/fixtures.js

```
util.printHelloWorld();
```

and I get a stack trace that says:

```
.../fibers/future.js:173) throw(ex);
ReferenceError: util is not defined
at app/test/fixtures.js:14:1
```

However,

```
util.printHelloWorld();
```

works just fine in the Chrome console. Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: is the definition of util in something like `if(Meteor.isClient)`? if so it would only run on the client side but not on the server

Comment: no it's not inside an if(Meteor.isClient) block.

Comment: Oh ok. What happens if you place `util.printHelloWorld();` in a `Meteor.startup(function() { util.printHelloWorld(); });`? stuff loaded in `lib` should load first so it would be the file ordering if it ends up working not too sure why though

Comment: It was the file ordering. When I was trying to assess the problem, I moved both files to my app root dir. Moving util.js back to my lib dir solved the problem. Thanks for your help!

Comment: What if you have a file interdependency within the lib folder?

Comment: You mentioned it was already in the lib folder? If there is an interdependency in the lib folder, the files are loaded in alphabetical order so just ensure your dependency is loaded first

Comment: Alphabetical order --got it. When I had them in the same directory fixtures.js was being loaded before util.js. Thanks Akshat. Question answered.